# How to always trigger jQuery then() callback?

Tags: jquery, promise

I have a situation where I have several functions which return deferred objects. I pass those deferred objects into `$.when()` and execute a `then()` callback when all of the deferred objects are resolved.

```
$.when(func1(), func2(), func3()).then(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
});
```

Sometimes none of the three functions return any deferred object, in that case `then()` callback is never executed. Is there a clean way to make sure that `then()` callback is always invoked?

Comment: `then()` will still invoke its success handler if none of the values passed to `$.when()` are deferred objects (e.g. `$.when("a", "b", "c").then(function() { alert("foo"); });` will alert `foo`). Are you referring to its fail handler?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Interesting point! So in order to always execute a success callback, I guess we can also try $.when("a", deferred_object_1, deferred_object_2).then(callback).

Comment: If both `deferred_object_1` and `deferred_object_2` are resolved later, then yes. As soon as one of them is rejected, though, the fail handler (the second argument to `then()`) will be invoked, and the success handler will be forgotten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .always() instead of .then() which will execute regardless.